# Как перебрать все комбинации из списка списков?

Tags: python, алгоритм, list

Есть некий список:

```
[
 [1, 2],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7]
]
```

Все списки могут иметь любую длину

Как получить всевозможные комбинации? Например:

> 1, 4, 7;
> 1, 5, 7;
> 2, 5, 7;
> 2, 6, 7;

Comment: Это называется декартово произведение

Comment: Исправил текст за вас. Учтите.

Comment: спасибо, буду знать

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: По-русски list  - "список".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вопрос заключается в [Декартовом произведении](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). В Python за это отвечает [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

На [него](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-%20of-lists) уже отвечали. Цитирую [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/533917/19829879) Kenan Banks:

```py
import itertools

nested_lists = [
    [1, 2],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7]
]

for part in itertools.product(*nested_lists):
    print(part)
```

Что равносильно

```py
for part in itertools.product([1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [7]):
    print(part)
```